# How to rename a batch of files via CLI when spaces are involved

Tags: command-line

I have a whole bunch of files that are like so:

```
x54y65.dat
```

and I want to prefix them with a specific phrase so that they look like so:

```
some prefix - x54y65.dat
```

Its that space after the hyphen that's getting me.

I tried:

```
 mv * some\ prefix\ -\ *
```

but that didn't work.  How do I do it?  Thanks

Comment: Ha!  Figured it out on my own!  Yay me.

    `rename 's//some prefix - /' *.dat`

Found the help here: [link](http://www.linuxandlife.com/2013/02/how-to-rename-multiple-files-with-rename.html)

Comment: You can add your comment as answer. See http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer .

Comment: actually, I tried that... but I didn't have the reputation to do so.  I see now that I can try again as its been > 8 hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the answer from the original author is correct, I think it is better to explain why the `mv` command listed in the question does not work.

The problem is a basic misunderstanding on the way in which a Unix shell works --- which is quite different form DOS command line. The special characters (*, ?, etc.) which select multiple files (they are called 'glob') works at the level of the shell, not of the commands. So the first command is expanded by the shell to

```
mv x54y56.dat x57y58.dat x59y60.dat "some prefix - *"
```

I am supposing that in the directory you have just this three files for sake of simplicity, and that you have no file which matches the name of `"some prefix - "` pattern --- so that the shell will probably let it as is. (I am using the quotes to embed spaces, I find it more easily readable than backlashes, although the fine details are in the manual for your shell).

Now, `mv a b c d` will try to move the files `a`, `b`, `c` to the directory `d`, and failing --- because `d` does not exist.

The `rename` solution, if you have the `rename` command, is the Right One. As the OP found,

```
rename 's//some prefix - /' *.dat
```

works ok. In the old good days, you where supposed to do

```
for i in *.dat; do
  mv "$i" "some prefix - $i"
done
```

to just do one move at time.

Answer (score 2):

```
rename 's//some prefix - /' *.dat
```

This uses regex-type syntax to rename all files with the specified extension (.dat) in one line.  It handles spaces easily, as it takes any characters encapsulated by the /

Answer (score 1):

```
mv x54y65.dat "some prefix - x54y65.dat"
```

Comment: That just renames one file only and doesn't explain anything. The question was about batch renaming.

Comment: Even still, I appreciate the clue about the quotes.  I'm so new, I didn't even know that.  When I Googled about spaces in Linux, I found that you should put a \ before the space.  I never saw anything about encapsulating.  However, that's standard from DOS days so I should have tried it (duh).  The answer I provided myself in my comments works better, however, as it does all files in one go.

Comment: `for i in *; do mv $i "some prefix-"$i;done` for rename multiple files